# How to get twitter like url appended string i.e. twitter inc?

Tags: url, ssl, safari, twitter

[image]

I want to add **Twitter, Inc.** like placeholder  **i.e. in green color in the url marked with red border** of twitter into my website also, **i.e. if my website is www.pks.com then PKS, Inc. should appear in green color inside url** Is there any API for this.

[image: Twitter, Inc Marked with red border]![Twitter, Inc Marked with red border]

> Also, **Google doesn't have it in its url**. What does this mean? Does it lack with the extra ssl certificate or is it a feature of safari browser. I don't know anything about this feature , please help me to know. And don't downvote if its  not clear leave a comment.

Comment: Don't down vote without proper explanation.

Comment: I assume you mean the green SSL bar in the browser?

Comment: And you want the green bar on Twitter on your website? Or you want the green bar on your website?

Comment: help me to open this question again by giving two up votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter uses a secured connection when accessing their website. This is called HTTPS.

To get the green bar, they use an Extended Validation SSL-certificate (EV SSL), available from all major certificate vendors such as VeriSign, Comodo, StartSSL, etc.

Comment: I'd also like to note that if you click on the text in Safari, it tells you what it's for and that other browsers show this in different ways.

Comment: Does google lack with the (EV SSL) as this is not shown in google.

Comment: It appears like Google is not using EV SSL for their domain, indeed. Technically, there's no need for the EV as it's intended as a way to reassure the user that not only the connection is safe, but also that the site belongs to a particular company.

However, since Google has its own Certificate Authority (CA), they might feel that there's no need for EV SSL.

Comment: On the screenshot above you are visting google through regular http:// - use https:// and yes, they'll encrypt requests and present their certification (you'll see green bar/text in the bar).